# OptionParser returning bool instead of argument?

Tags: ruby, optparse

When I run [this sample](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html) from the OptionParser documentation:

```
require 'optparse'
options = {}
OptionParser.new do |opts|
    opts.banner = "Usage: example.rb [options]"
    opts.on("-v", "--[no-]verbose", "Run verbosely") do |v|
        options[:verbose] = v
    end
end.parse!
p options
p ARGV
```

and type: `ruby test.rb -v 100`, it returns:

```
{:verbose=>true}
["100"]
```

Shouldn't verbose be `100`, not a boolean?

I have no idea about this, does anyone have any advice?

Comment: When I ran the minimal section from the link provided it produced `{:verbose=>true}` as well

Comment: `--[no]verbose` specifies that `verbose` is a boolean switch.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You've specified that the `-v` option does not have an argument:

```
opts.on("-v", ...
```

If you want it to take an argument then you have to say so:

```
opts.on("-v n", "--verbose=n", ...
#-----------^
```

And if you want to force `n` to be an integer, then:

```
opts.on('-v n', '--verbose=n', OptionParser::DecimalInteger, ...
```

You want to start reading at the [`make_switch`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html#method-i-make_switch) docs (such as it is) and then reverse engineer the examples.

Don't feel bad about being confused, the OptionParser documentation isn't quite the best thing ever.

Comment: i got it....  i chane my program. and it works.   Thanks a lot . i will go to read the make_switch docs. Thanks !