# Ruby Options parser not reading command line options

Tags: ruby, parsing, command-line-arguments

Im trying to use the Ruby builtin options parser

I have this file

File parser.rb
     #!/usr/bin/env ruby
     require 'optparse'
     require 'pp'

```
 class parser

 def initialize(args)
 @options = Hash.new()
 @op = OptionParser.new do |opts|
 @options[:verbose] = false
opts.on('-v', '--verbose', 'Output more information') do 
    @options[:verbose] = true
end

@options[:quick] = false
opts.on( '-q', '--quick', 'Perform the task quickly' ) do 
    @options[:quick] = true
end

@options[:logfile] = nil
opts.on( '-l', '--logfile FILE', 'Write log to FILE' ) do|file|
           @options[:logfile] = file
end

opts.on( '-h', '--help', 'Display this screen' ) do
         puts opts
    exit
end

    @options[:sID] = "-1"
opts.on('-sID', '--senderID', 'Sender ID used by device') do |sID|
     @options[:sID] = sID
end

@options[:rID] = "-1"
opts.on('-rID', '--receiverID', 'Receiver ID used by device') do |rID|
    @options[:rID] = rID
end

  @op.parse!
  @op
  end

 def getOptionsHash
 @options
  end
```

then Im trying to use this class in the file below

```
 #!/usr/bin/env ruby

 # Setup Bundler
 require 'rubygems'
 require 'bundler/setup'

 require_relative 'parser'


 #Variables in the options hash in parser.rb

 op = Parser.new(ARGV)
 pp op.getOptionsHash()
```

when I run this on the command line without args it uses default values:
      ./push_test.rb

I get the following output:

```
 {:verbose=>false,
  :quick=>false,
   :logfile=>nil,
  :sID=>"-1",
  :rID=>"-1",

  }
```

when I run this on the command line with args:
      ./push_test.rb -sID "33"

I get the following output:

```
  {:verbose=>false,
   :quick=>false,
   :logfile=>nil,
  :sID=>"ID",
  :rID=>"-1",

  }
```

Why is the sID not being set to 33?

Can anyone help please?Ive tried to figure this out but cant make any headway

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange behavior of Ruby's OptionParser lib?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577478/strange-behavior-of-rubys-optionparser-lib)

Comment: Thanks for this tip, I tried to change my script to follow this answer but that is not working for me either.

This is the line that modified in my script:   opts.on('-mID mID', '--msgID=mID', 'Message ID used by device') do |mID|    But Im still getting the same output on my terminal


msgID is still not being set to the number passed in to the command line args

Comment: You need not to specify argument at both switch versions, one is enough. On the other hand by OptParser nature you cann't define short switch name longer then just *one* character (after the dash).

Answer (score 1):

Seems the short switch has to be a single character `-s`

`./push_test.rb -sID "33"`

outputs:

`{:verbose=>false, :quick=>false, :logfile=>nil, :sID=>"ID", :rID=>"-1" }`

because everything after -s to the first white space will be assigned to :sID, in your case its the word "ID" that follows "-s",  hence you are getting `:sID =>"ID"`

`./push_test.rb -s "33"` will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

From the OptParser [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html#method-i-make_switch):

> ```
> Short style switch::   Specifies short style switch which takes a
> mandatory, optional or no   argument. It's a string of the following
> form:
>   "-xMANDATORY"
>   "-x[OPTIONAL]"
>   "-x"
> ```

So at specifying switch `-sID` you define switch `-s` with argument named `ID` - something different than you were probably expecting.